# Manager does not give me negative feedback directly?

Tags: performance-reviews, new-hires

I am on my trial period of 6 months in Europe and had my performance review last week, which was very negative. I was told that if I do not improve some things, they will let me go. The feedback was delivered in a meeting by two managers. My own manager was not attending, since (s)he is on trial period as well.

I booked a meeting with my manager the next day to discuss my performance review. (S)he asked very happy how it went, and was very surprised by the negative feedback, and told me to not worry about my position. I do not work with the managers who I had the meeting with and they asked about my performance from my manager. Furthermore, my manager has never informed me about my performance problems.

What is going on?
How should I proceed?

Comment: "What is going on?" - You should ask your manager.  If these other managers, gave you negative feedback based on your managers feedback about you, then your manager needs to explain what happened.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you should clarify with your manager swiftly.

Make a list of the aspects to improve or with negative performance that you were told by the other managers. Then, ask you manager for clarification, and also pointers on what to improve from those aspects. Something like:

> Hello Manager. I was told by [the other managers] that my performance was unsatisfactory and that I will be terminated if I don't improve on certain things. They mentioned improvement needed on [X, Y, Z,]... You told me not to worry about my position but getting that feedback from [the other managers] leaves me unsettled.
>
> Could you help me understand why those managers think I am under-performing? Do you have any pointers on the aspects they mentioned? Could this be some sort of mistake?

Perhaps the other managers mixed up your profile with another employee under evaluation... or, under a more negative optic, your manager is not being truthful to you...

Either way, as you obtain clarification from this whole situation, you can reflect on the aspects you were told that you could improve, and see if you feel there is indeed room for improvement.

Comment: This message seems a bit formal, especially for someone who seems to be already on your side. Personally, I would be worried about layoffs. Maybe the other managers know something that your manager doesn't, or maybe they're trying to protect their own budget by making sure the employee of a rival manager doesn't get a raise.